# Navigating from TableViewController to Tab View Controller

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3, xcode8, xcode-storyboard

I'm making a App where the user has to pick an item, that is getting used in the main pages of the app.

I would like to navigate from the item, showed in a table view, to the main page.

The first page is a Table View and I have to navigate to a Tab Bar view. 
In the Storyboard there is no option to drag from the cell to the Tab Bar View.

[UI Storyboard view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2i8b1.png)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: One of my project I did like this `UITabBarController *tabController = (UITabBarController *)[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"TabBarController"]; [self presentViewController:tabController animated:true completion:nil];`. I didn't connect to tabviewcontroller directly called when my button tapped. Try this may work.

Comment: That could work, the only problem is that I want to send data to the tabbed controller.

Comment: Did you get any solutions? Try some shared instances object or `NSUserDefault` and `NSNotificaitonCenter` (worst case).

Comment: Did not find a solution. But I will try to Use NSUserDefault, I think that could work.